# Sphere collision resolution when colliding with multiple meshes

Tags: collision-detection, physics, 3d

I'm writing my own player collision physics and I'm stuck at collision resolution part. I have sphere as a player and scene made of static meshes. Collision resolution works fine when player is colliding with single mesh. When there's more than one collision point player starts bouncing in between.

[image]

And here's how my collision detection loop looks like:

```
function update(delta) {
    var step = this.player.velocity.scale(delta);
    this.player.position.add(step);

    var collisions = getSphereCollisions(sphere); // Array of penetration vectors

    for (var collision of collisions) {
        this.player.position.add(collision);
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is that collision vectors are pushing player back and forth against each other. I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: You may be interested in [Avoid shaking artifacts in 3D continuous collision detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/181936/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory I'll take a look. Thank you!